# OOP - How to create an interface in Reason

Tags: oop, ocaml, reason

Let's say I have the following `abstractProductA` class with a public method called `methodA` :

```
class abstractProductA = {
  pub methodA => "name";
};
```

I would like to create an interface that says function `methodA` should always return a `string`. Something similar to

```
interface abstractProductA {
  abstractProductA(): string
}
```

only in reason, and then have class implement it. Any suggestions are more than welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're really asking for it seems is how to define and use an abstract class, which is called a virtual class in OCaml/Reason:

```
class virtual virtualProductA = {
  pub virtual methodA: string;
};

class abstractProductA = {
  inherit virtualProductA;
  pub methodA = "name";
};
```

An interface is more for consumers to abstract away an implementation, and while a virtual class can be used as an interface by itself, since OCaml/Reason objects are structurally typed you can also just specify the object type you need. And of course you can bind it to a name if you like:

```
type interfaceA = {.
  methodA : string
};

let f (p: interfaceA) => Js.log p#methodA;
f (new abstractProductA);
```

Comment: I was wondering if you could expand your "structurally typed" answer in two ways. One, go into detail about what "structurally typed" means. Second, Insert code as to how it would be used with abstractProductA class. Thank you.

Comment: Structural typing, in this context, just means you don't have to define the relationships in advance. You don't have to explicitly specify that `abstractProductA` implements `interfaceA`, it does, implicitly, by simply implementing the same "structure", ie. having methods with the same names and types.

Comment: Nice. So I would imagine best practice is to use structural typing over abstract classes in this context, right?

Comment: I've added a usage example for the interface above.  You could also just replace the `interfaceA` type of `f` with `virtualProductA`, to use that definition as the "interface"

Comment: "So I would imagine best practice is to use structural typing over abstract classes in this context"

Depends a bit on context, structural typing is more lightweight, but sometimes you actually do need explicit relationships.

Comment: It can also sometimes useful to add constraint to the self type to ensure that the class is a subtype of a given class type, e.g. `constraint 'self = {. m: string ; .. }`

Comment: @octachron Right, the Reason syntax for this would be `{.. m: string }` though.

I've also glossed over some details of object types that might make it more difficult to understand and use, like the whole row polymorphism thing and the inability to bind it to a name if that's needed.

Comment: I haven't used reason, just  a big fan of ocaml. 
Structural typings real benefit over nominal typing, is the fact that it encourages you to write your code in a more modular way,  in regards to nominal typing being more suited for more complicated relationships, I honestly think this is a misconception based on people being used to multiple inheritance, in my experience using functors and include statements as substitutes, suit my needs fine.

Comment: @XGoVoid Just to put you mind at ease: OOP isn't idiomatic in Reason either. Functors and includes are much preferred, but it's for obvious reasons not the first thing that's taught. OOP is actively discouraged, but I'm starting to think we might need to put more emphasis on how to effectively use the module system.

Comment: @glennsl, that wasn't the reason why I haven't used reason, I write a lot of infrastructure code, I can go 8 months to a year without writing a line of JS, or do any front end development, (yes I know ocaml has js interop but )  I like Ocamls syntax more,

Comment: @glennsl, that wasn't the reason why I haven't used reason, I write a lot of infrastructure code, so I'm more of an erlang or ocaml + c kind of guy. 

Thus I rarely write anything in javascript. 

(Yes I know ocaml has js interop but I mean the reason why reason is hot, is it's syntactically revamped to be familiar, and it's tool chain makes it more seamless than say using js_of_ocaml ). 

Honestly, the only thing I am scared that Reason will have  the same relation to ocaml as Elixir to Erlang. Which is funny since they are my two favorite languages.

Comment: Worth noting this is discussed in the Real World OCaml book pg. 230.